# how to get div content by role javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, dom

I'm trying to get feed content from facebook dom.

```
<div role="feed">
```

so i did that:

```
querySelectorAll($("div[role='feed']"))
```

like this:
[get div by role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578589/jquery-get-element-by-role-tag)
but it returns undifend result.
I tried some more similar way but still get undifend.

It is possible to get this data?
thanks

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` is not needed in your code above, since `$("div[role='feed']")` should find the element (or use `querySelector("div[role='feed']")`).  However, since it's Facebook you may need to rethink things.  Facebook does a lot of client-side building, so it may be that the element simply isn't on the page when you're looking for it.

Comment: side note: scraping is not allowed on facebook. what´s the use case for this?

Answer (score 3):

Please remove `$`. It's not needed and might throw an `undefined` error. Are you running after the page has loaded? Are you using `.innerHTML` to get the HTML contents? This works for me:

```html
<div role="feed">Hello</div>
<script>
console.log(document.querySelector('div[role="feed"]').innerHTML);
</script>
```

In case, if you aren't running after your page has loaded, put your code inside `onload` event of `window` object.

You should change your code this way:

```html
<script>
// Loading script before element.
window.onload = function () {
  console.log(document.querySelector('div[role="feed"]').innerHTML);
}
</script>
<div role="feed">Hello</div>
```

This works if you are loading script before element.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you don't need `querySelectorAll()` to get the DOM you can achieve this with `$("div[role='feed']")`. Since you are using `querySelectorAll()`, it accept string which must be a valid CSS selector string; if it's not, a SyntaxError exception is thrown. Since you are using wrong syntax, it returns undefined.

And you need [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to get content of `div` in jQuery. [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.

```js
console.log($("div[role='feed']").text());
console.log($("div[role='feed']"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="feed">
so i did that:
</div>
```

Comment: The question says, he's getting undefined. Also the other question he linked to has everything.

Comment: Er... Not exactly. Yours isn't wrong, but kinda not useful as I *believe* the OP might be doing it right. May be, now your answer seems to be complete. `:)`

Comment: Yes - it is wrong.  The code for selecting the div is returning *undefined*, so neither `.text` or `.innerHTML` will return anything.  Also, if the OP wants HTML then using `.text` is definitely wrong.

Comment: Sorry, but I see nothing in your edit (done before I commented) that changes what I posted.  This answer is plain wrong.

Comment: No - you've not addressed the problem at all.  Have you tried `document.querySelectorAll($("a-selector"));`?  You should have posted comments to clarify the question, but you posted an irrelevant answer instead.

Comment: Yes.  Now read the question again, with that in mind.  The OP's problem is not what you are addressing.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing JavaScript and jQuery.

- You don't need `$()` to do that with `.querySelectorAll()`
- You don't need `.querySelectorAll()` to do that with `$()`

You can do any of the following to select the `div` with `role="feed"`:

```js
let divs_js = document.querySelectorAll("div[role='feed']");
console.log('Elements matched:', divs_js.length);

let divs_jq = $("div[role='feed']");
console.log('Elements matched:', divs_jq.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="feed"></div>
<div role="not-feed"></div>
<div role="feed"></div>
<div role="feed"></div>
<div role="not-feed"></div>
```

⋅
⋅
⋅

Here is an example of what you can do to get the content, then:

```js
console.log("Using JS:");
let divs_js = document.querySelectorAll("div[role='feed']");
divs_js.forEach(function(elm){
  console.log(elm.innerHTML); // or .innerText, according to your needs
});

// ----------------------
console.log("---------");
console.log("Using jQ:");
let divs_jq = $("div[role='feed']");
$(divs_jq).each(function(){
  console.log($(this).html()); // or .text(), according to your needs
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="feed">feed 1</div>
<div role="not-feed">not feed 1</div>
<div role="feed">feed 2</div>
<div role="feed">feed 3</div>
<div role="not-feed">not feed 2</div>
```

Hope it helps.